# Fade Rows Far From Center

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

I am currently using a vertical monitor for my vim setup. I absolutely love being able to view 100+ lines of code at once. My eyes can scan longer and more complicated blocks of code.

However, I have noticed that there are times when being able to see 100+ lines of code is actually quite distracting. There are cases when i'm really only concerned with 5-10 lines. This is especially problematic if I look away to my second monitor to read something in my browser; when my eyes go back to vim, I have to rescan the whole monitor to remember where I was.

The ideal situation, personal preference-wise, would be to dynamically fade all rows a certain number of lines away from the center row with a convenient key binding. This would give me the flexibility to zone into narrower blocks of code and be able to quickly get back to looking at the bigger picture if I want to.

Does anyone know a solution like this? If not, I would also appreciate alternative solutions to the same problem or similar problem, which I would generally describe as "the frequent changing of the scope of focus in my editor throughout the day".

Answer (score 1):

[limelight.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim) works great for fading paragraphs of text. I don't know if it works for code blocks also. It can still be a good starting point to look up the fading functionality, since getting current cursor line in vimscript is trivial, with functions line() / winline().

Answer (score 1):

Another plugin option is [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn), which has editing benefits as well.

I’ve seen people use a trick to flash cursorline and cursor column as well, as a sort of "where am I." This is not hard to do, but I’ll see if I can find the exact code later.